# Remove default css from angular2-collapsible

Tags: angular, animation, collapsable

How to remove the default animation from angular2-collapsible. There is a default css on this collapsible[i-e boxshadow and overflow]. I tried over writing, what i want is to completely remove this css. 
Here is the link for angular2-collapsible
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-collapsible

Comment: add some code that you have tried so far

Comment: just override the css code in parent file, as per requirements

Comment: overriding in any css file is working. but when we open nd close the panels, the default css appears for like 1 2 seconds. which is looking bad on my dark theme

Comment: main issue was 'VIEW ENCAPSULATION IN ANGULAR'
after setting it to none resolved my problem.